# VirtualBox - Centos

Tags: centos, virtualbox, system-installation, virtual-machine

I am new to technology and am trying to learning linux administration with Linux Academy.  I am following the Linux Essentials course and they are showing me how to install CentOS 8 on VirtualBox.  I have followed their steps and gone through the entire installation process (including creating Root Password and creating user account).  After the [installation is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uAsO.jpg), I click on the reboot button and it only gives me the [option to Install again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxISA.jpg).

It looks like I can only go through the installation and not actually use the Operating System.  Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Windows 10 64-Bit.  Virtual Box Version 6.1.12 r139181 (Qt5.6.2) and the Centos ISO says it is version 8.2.

Please let me know if there is any additional information that you would need in order to figure out what is going on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not unmounting the ISO CD after the install is complete.

When you get to the install is complete, use the "devices" menu at the top of the screen to optical drives - > Remove disk from virtual drive.

Then reboot. You should see the usual grub menu at that point.